# Finding highest number by team name in FILE I/O

Tags: java, file-io

I have a team.txt file which includes: name raised$ and teamName i.e:

```
Name    Raised   Team
Peter   400.27   Alpha
John    350.99   Beta
Anne    1200.00  Gamma
```

Now I now how to look for the int and add them all up BUT I have no idea how can I distinguish on how to write a program that looks at the numbers and tells me which team raised most money. This is what I have so far:

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("team.txt"));
input.nextLine();  // get rid of header line
```

Comment: utilizing while(team.hasNext()) where in the loop i will have the following:
1)adds the int for all three teams 2)outputs the teamName with highest raised amount.

Comment: do you just want the highest value, or do you want the highest value and also the associated name/team to it?

Comment: both the value with name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a split for each line. The `split` method turns the line into an array of Strings based on the spcified delimiter. In this case, I used one or more spaces as a delimiter `\\s+`

```
double alphaTotal = 0;
double betaTotal = 0;
double gammaTotal = 0;

input.nextLine();
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = input.nextLine();
     String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
     double raised = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1].trim());

     if ("Alpha".equals(tokens[2])){
         alphaTotal += raised;
     } esle if ("Beta".equals(tokens[2])) {
         betaTotal += raised;
     } else if ("Gamma".equals(tokens[2])) {
         gammaTotal += raised;
     }
}

// Print out the winner
if (alphaTotal > betaTotal && alphaTotal > gammaTotal){
    System.out.println("Team Aplha wins with $" + alphaTotal);
} else if ( .... .... .... ){
    ....
} else if ( .... .... .... ){
    ....
}
```

The array would look like this after the split

```
tokens = {"Peter", "400.27", "Alpha"};
```

The `400.27` is initially a `String`, so you have to parse it.

Simple `if` statements will determine which team is on each line.

Comment: never worked with the token before. why do we create String line and what is the line.split does for us? but this looks like what I'm looking for

Comment: Read the line as a `String`. Then split it into three Strings. Take the middle String and parse it to a `double`. Use that `double` to add to total. I made a few changes, see if that works. Should be fine, assuming your file is like in your post.

Comment: I messed up. I deleted the `.` after `parse`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "raised"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at fileTeam.main(fileTeam.java:25)

Comment: Does you file just have that one line at the top you need to get rid of, then the rest of the lines look like `String double String`?

Comment: @keeskillet you were right, for some reasons I deleted to skip the header. adding this fixed the problem input.nextLine();  // get rid of header line  . Thank you so much for your great input. Great respect.

Comment: do I need to close the file for example if i want to SOP the txt file first and then find the winner?

Comment: what do you mean print the file? You want to print its entire contents? You can print it out in the `while` loop. After each `String line = input.nextLine()`, just add the `SOP(line)`. After you don't need the scanner anymore, It is good practice to close it.

Comment: coudnt get it to work but when SOP(line)put in the same loop worked perfectly.  Thank you so much again! 

NOTE. just wondering why it didn't work when in the other loop? just because the scanner was at the end of the txt file? If yes how would I fix it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what loop you're referring to? If you mean you created another loop with the same scanner, then yes. You would need to close the scanner, create a new scanner with the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a counter that holds the current highest value raised, and also keep a string that holds the highest team name raised.

```
int highest = 0; String highestTeam = "";
while (!EOF()) {
    // Read in team name, raised value
    if (raisedValue < highest) {
        highest = raisedValue;
        highestTeam = teamName;
    }
}
```

At the end, `highest` will contain the highest raised value, and `highestTeam` will be the name of the team that raised the most.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. What is !EOF? and how did you scan the line for int? since everything is in a string

Comment: @user2985347 EOF is End Of File. So while you have *not* reached the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You said you could add them all up, so I'll assume you can get them in an array. Let's say `double[] arr` contains all of the double values.

This is how to determine the highest value:

```
 double max = 0; // initially max number is 0
 for (double i: arr) // for every double in the array of doubles
     if (i > max) max = i; // if this number is > the last recorded max, 
                           // set this as the new max
```